# How to differentiate the opposite meanings of 'sanction'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, antonyms, legalese, auto-antonyms

> “If you want to know the law and nothing else, you must look at it as a bad
> man, who cares only for the material consequences, of which such knowledge enables
> him to predict not as a good one, who finds his reasons for conduct, whether
> inside the law or outside of it, in the vaguer **sanctions** of conscience.” “The Path
> of the Law,” 10 *Harv. L. Rev.* at 459.

Source: pp 126 footnote, Thinking like a Lawyer, Frederick Schauer

How can I determine the correct meaning of 'sanction', out of these two opposites? Please explain the steps or thought processes, for want of doing so by myself in the future?

> **[Definition 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sanction?q=sanctions#sanction__6).** A threatened penalty for disobeying a law or rule:
>
> **Definition 2.** Official permission or approval for an action:

Comment: As an experienced English speaker, I have difficulty understanding that sentence!

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/a/48845/16310

Comment: I would choose to read it as in your definition 2. Why? Because it makes more sense that way.

Answer (score 3):

It's the second meaning, *official permission or approval for an action*. Really, the reasoning comes down to [what Damkerng T. said](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31987/how-to-differentiate-the-opposite-meanings-of-sanction#comment60155_31987): which definition makes the most sense? Let's examine the relevant portion of the sentence:

> [A good man] finds his reasons for conduct, whether inside the law or outside of it, in the vaguer sanctions of conscience.

It's quite common to think of *a good man* and *a law abiding man* as synonymous. But legality and morality or justice are not the same. Thus, a truly *good* man is driven by his sense of ethics (i.e. *conscience*) rather than the law of the land. This is why *his reasons for conduct* may be *inside the law or outside of it*.

But this does not mean he acts at random or on pure caprice; he still has *his reasons*. The motivations for his conduct are approved of (or not) by *his conscience*. So there is still some measure of whether or not his actions are permitted or justifiable; it's just that the ultimate approval comes from wholly within the man, rather than from some external source.

It would make little sense at best if *sanctions* here meant *penalty for violating a law*. Because the *vague sanctions* originate from *his conscience*, that means the punishment for violating his personal ethics (the only reasonable meaning here, since his actions aren't dictated by society's laws) would be an ill-defined sense of unease or unhappiness.

And he *finds his reasons for conduct* in these *vague sanctions*. It would be strange indeed to claim that a man would base his entire *raison d'être* on whether or not an act caused him mild pangs of unspecific discomfort. It makes a lot more sense to say that he bases his choices on whether or not his conscience approves of them.

This is especially true given the context. Schauer appears to be exploring the motivations and evolution underpinning laws, their formations and their justifications. Good men are most often law abiding, but the law is not what makes them good. While everyone has different qualms, people's consciences are, in general, remarkably similar on the broad points of ethics (which are a substantial portion of what laws address):

> Do not kill, do not rape, do not steal. These are principles which every man of every faith can embrace.
>   <sub>-*The Boondock Saints*; [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0144117/), relevant [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhWw943avOc) (not safe for work)</sub>

Comment: The example contrasts "a bad man" with "a good one".  The bad man "cares only for the material consequences". The "conscience" comments are made about the "good one".

Comment: +1. Thanks. Would you please enlarge upon your 4th paragraph whose topic sentence is 'It would make little sense...'. Conscience can be corrupt, so if definition 2 were chosen for the meaning of 'sanction', then can't a corrupt conscience still cause an 'ill-defined sense of unease or unhappiness'? The sanctions (assuming definition 2) of conscience would punish him?  I don't perceive what makes "little sense" here?

Comment: Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as comments?

Answer (score 0):

The quote can be read either way.  Both ways are not only equally meaningful, they effectively mean the same thing!  The gist is that the hypothetical "good [man]"'s motives are internally generated by his conscience, which is both hidden from outside observation and subtle.  This makes it harder to manipulate the "good [man]" by simply changing rewards, penalties, and chances of being caught.

It is possible that the author meant the quote to be read both ways.  Many of the best turns of phrase have multiple meanings.

The example passage is consistent with the theory of utilitarianism, which considers both "pleasures" (such as the positive meanings of "sanction"), and "pains" (such as the negative meanings of "sanction").

Jeremy Bentham developed the moral theory of "Utilitarianism".  He distinguished "four classes" of "pleasures and pains":  physical, moral, political, and religious.  He considered seven aspects of each pleasure or pain:  intensity, duration, certainty, proximity, productiveness, purity, and extent.  Bentham recommended legislative reforms.  Not only was he careful to point out the limits of what could be legislated, he pointed out that bad laws could undermine social and religious sanctions in society.

Jeremy Bentham's "Principles of Legislation" is a good introduction to utilitarianism.  My 1961 edition of *Introduction to Contemporary Civilization in the West* has a coherent 26 page set of excerpts from Bentham's article "Principles of Legislation" in the 1931 edition of *The Theory of Legislation*.  According to my textbook, "This work first appeared in Etienne Dumont's French version (*Traités de legislation civile et penale*, 1802) and was translated into English by Richard Hildreth in 1864."

Answer (score 0):

"Sanctions" refer to something that  the authorities feel very strongly about, either positively or negatively.

"The U.S. government has sanctions against Iran." (bad)"The U.S. government sanctions solar energy." (good)

You can use the context to differentiate between kinds of sanction. The only thing that is clear is that the government is not "neutral" about the matter in question.